# Windows DNS hooks

Tags: windows, dns, winsock

How does Windows resolve DNS and how can I intercept the calls, in order to inject my own domains?
I need this in an application, and running my own DNS server or modifying the hosts file is not a solution.

Comment: The worm Win32/Conficker does that, interventing with the DNSCache service. If nobody has an answer, you can try searching information about how the worm does that.

Comment: Thanks. It would be interesting to grok through its source code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your purpose is, but there are several options.
[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DnsHijack.aspx?msg=1893010) includes something that might help you here. It seems to do what you need to do.
Now, the other solution might involve abit of work of your own that might be inappropiate for the project.
For one, you need to figure out if the following [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(VS.85).aspx) is the one responsible for DNS lookups in the applications you want to modify. The next stage is basically implementing the CodeProject code yourself, set up a global hook using [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) and in the returning trampoline insert your modifying code.

I'm still not quite sure why you need to do this though, if you would provide more detail on the end goal, you might get better answers.

Comment: Thank you. I'd like a solution to work for all processes. But I think your answer just gave me enough guidance.

Comment: I would assume that the Microsoft Detours and CodeProject example (which uses Detours) won't work with apps compiled without Win32 API. I assume that means if you download the 64bit version of an app? Not certain. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for Hooking DNSQuery() function calls in dnsapi.lib/dnsap.dll