# Intercept DNS Queries Windows

Tags: windows, dns, hook

I would like to be able to intercept DNS queries on my Windows computer by "hooking" into "all of the DNS functions" ([Is it possible to intercept dns queries using LSP/SPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319304/is-it-possible-to-intercept-dns-queries-using-lsp-spi)).

So, for example, if I have a config file with contents:

*.example.com

I am hoping to handle these requests with a response of 127.0.0.1. Wildcarding doesn't work in the hosts file (and I also might try logging some queries, too). This can be done from a network level; I want to do it through the host operating system, partially out of a perfectionist bent.

Someone else suggested "Hooking DNSQuery() function calls in dnsapi.lib/dnsap.dll" ([Windows DNS hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317067/windows-dns-hooks)).

Will the mhook library allow me to do what I want to do?

Lastly: I have no intention of making malware; I want to take a bit more control over the traffic my computer(s) are creating.

Comment: Create a DNS proxy like this bloke? https://codemyroad.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/monitoring-home-web-traffic-with-a-local-dns-proxy/

Comment: @AlexK.: A DNS proxy could accomplish the stated goals; I'll have to provide further clarification above. When out and about with a laptop, I'd prefer not to be tweaking local DNS server settings when, say, I connect to a wifi capture portal system.

From a more "idealist" perspective, I feel this (greater control over and visibility into DNS requests) is something that would ideally be done at the operating system level, rather than the network.